# Discord.py lastfm bot command issue

Tags: python, discord, command, last.fm

I'm making a `lastfm` bot in discord.py and it says for line 27
`"Undetermined string lateral"`. Idk how to fix it

Issue is:

```
track_list += f"{track['name']} by

{track['artist']['name']}\n"

# Get the top tracks of the user with the Last.fm

@client.command()

async def toptracks(ctx, username):


API client

tracks = lastfm_client.user.get_top_tracks(user=

username)

# Create a string with the track name and artist

for each track

track_list = ""

for track in tracks:

track_list += f"{track['name']} by

{track['artist']['name']}\n
```

Comment: Which line in your listing is line 27? Also from looking at all the code I would assume that there is at least one `"` missing at the end.